# How do I ensure a Behat Scenario, that creates a new Node, navigates as expected?

Tags: 8, testing

My Behat Scenario creates new content, successfully simulating every step until the new Node is created. In doing so it navigates through every new page in the regular admin sequence as you'd expect.

But, after the *Save* button is pressed on `/node/add/myContentType`, even though the Node is correctly created, the page in the session remains at `/node/add/myContentType` and doesn't progress to `/node/n` as happens when done manually.

The scenario is tagged `@javascript` and I am using `phantomjs`

I'm baffled as to how to resolve this issue. I've tried adding waits for javascript inactivity. e.g like waiting for batch completion:

```
$this->getSession()->wait(180000, 'jQuery("#updateprogress").length === 0');
```

or like waiting for AJAX completion:

```
$this->getSession()->wait(1000, 'typeof(jQuery)=="undefined" ||
    jQuery("#autocomplete").length === 0');
```

... but I think waiting is not  the issue; more likely to do with the driver?

My workaround is to split this into two Scenarios; the second Scenario navigates explicitly to the newly-created Node. But ideally, to keep things as realistic as possible,  I would rather the person writing our test features can do creation and inspection in the same Scenario.

Comment: This might help you https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10389